# What type of cement is used to repair foundations?

Tags: flooring, kitchens, foundation, cement

We're in the process of remodeling our kitchen and we just pulled up the tiles. We found a few spots where there are large gouges or holes if you will, in the foundation. I'm guessing they were there from a previous remodel?

Anyway, we need to repair them and I was wondering if there was a certain type of cement that is required. The last guys just filled the holes in with the stuff you use for tiles and it chipped up and didn't stick at all.

There is also a long crack (as seen in the photo), should that be repaired in the same way or does that require something different?

[image]

**UPDATE:** I ended up finding this question: [What cement product should I use to fix a hole in my slab?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18558/what-cement-product-should-i-use-to-fix-a-hole-in-my-slab) and used the cement listed in the answer

[image]

but it was too rocky. I need something very smooth. I filled the deeper sections enough with the quickete stuff, but now I need to top it off to get the smooth finish.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing more research and found this stuff
[image]

and it is doing exactly what I was looking for. It's a very fine power, no rocks or coarse sand, so it's great for filling in holes with a smooth finish.

Answer (score 1):

There's a product called sand mix that you should be able to find at most hardware stores & home centers. It is a mix of cement and sand rather than cement and large aggregate, so it's good for filling shallower imperfections.

Here are two examples:
https://www.quikrete.com/productlines/sandtoppingmix.asp
http://www.sakrete.com/products/detail.cfm/prod_alias/Sand-Mix

Note that for uses in thicknesses under 1" you'll probably need an additive (read the data sheet for details). There are adhesion promoters you can look into as well - again, they'll be mentioned in the data sheet for the product.

Comment: thanks, but a little late. I ended up getting quickrete concrete patcher